# Finding individual values from cumulative mean in R Dataframe

Tags: r, recursion

I am having troubles finding how to find individual values from the running mean in an R dataframe.

I have an R dataframe:

```
x ID  Mean
1   1   1
1   2   5
2   1   3
2   2   6
```

Where the mean is the mean for the x measurements for the specific ID in the dataframe.

To find the individual values at each x value rather than the mean, I was thinking that I needed to apply a recursive function on the dataframe and group by the ID. How could I do this in a dataframe while grouping by one of the values when any apply function wouldn't have access to the previous entry in the dataframe?

When completed and appended to the dataframe, I am hoping it to look like this:

```
x ID  Mean  IndivValues
1   1   1     1
1   2   5     5
2   1   3     5
2   2   6     7
```

Comment: @RonakShah Edited to include wanted output

Comment: It's unclear how you arrive at the new column. How is it calculated?

Comment: I think your 3rd value should be 4.  IN that case, just do `df1 %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(IndivValues = cumsum(Mean))`

Comment: @RichScriven I am trying to reverse the cumulation of the mean. x is the number of individual values that are averaged in the mean. So when x=1, The mean is just equal to the individual value, but for x=2, the mean is the average of the first individual value and the second. The output to IndivValues should be that second value necessary to find that mean. When x=3, it will be the value necessary to get the mean at x=3. I have the cumulative means, but just need to find the most recent value necessary to change the mean at x-1 for that ID to the mean at x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's much easier to calculate this from totals -> to individual observation, as below:

**Example data.frame:**

```
df <- read.table(text='
 x ID  Mean
 1   1   1
 1   2   5
 2   1   3
 2   2   6
 ', header=T)
```

**Solution:**

```
library(dplyr); library(magrittr)
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate( 
    total = mean * x,
    ind_value = total - lag(total, default=0) )



## A tibble: 4 x 5
## Groups:   ID [2]
#      x    ID  Mean     total ind_value
#  <int> <int> <int>     <int>     <int>
#1     1     1     1        1         1
#2     1     2     5        5         5
#3     2     1     3        6         5
#4     2     2     6       12         7
```